# How can I be sure a thread is complete before continuing?

Tags: android, java-threads

I've just started using threads in Android java. I'm launching a thread from my main activity, but I need to be sure it has completed before continuing with the main logic flow.

The code is:

```
    MyClass myclass = new MyClass();

       new Thread() {
           public void run() {
               myclass.myMethod();  // Do some work here

           }
       }.start();

// More work here which assumes myMethod() has completed
```

The work in myMethod involves a url call, so it might take a few seconds and I need to be sure it's complete before continuing.
Can anybody suggest the best way to do this?
Many thanks

Comment: "but I need to be sure it has completed before continuing with the main logic flow" -- that is **not** what you should be doing. "The work in myMethod involves a url call" -- then use something like [OkHttp and its `enqueue()` option](https://square.github.io/okhttp/recipes/#asynchronous-get-kt-java), where your "more work" goes into the callback to be invoked after the download has completed. OkHttp will handle the background thread for you.

Comment: Thanks for the link, but as a newbie to this I find it adds a lot of complex code. Why is so wrong simply to put the object call into a thread? Some stuff I've seen says that a "join" would work but I can't work out the syntax.

Comment: "but as a newbie to this I find it adds a lot of complex code" -- perhaps you should start with a simpler project, or learn Android app development from a book or course.  "Why is so wrong simply to put the object call into a thread?" -- forking a thread is reasonable, though we often do not use `Thread` directly. However, "I need to be sure it has completed before continuing with the main logic flow" and your suggestion to use `join()` suggests that you really do not understand what is going on here and why we fork threads for network I/O.

Comment: Can anyone be helpful rather than insulting? Surely it must be a general problem that a thread is launched to do something or other, and at a later point in the app you need to check that it's completed its work?

Comment: Summary information on the topic is found in [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/background/threading). The subject is usually covered in books and courses on Android app development. It is a fairly complex topic, the sort of thing that is beyond a simple Stack Overflow answer. That is why I steered you towards a simple solution (OkHttp and `enqueue()`) that happens also to be a fairly popular approach for your specific problem (doing some Web I/O in the background).

Comment: The reason for using threads for I/O is to not freeze the UI while that I/O is going on. However, that implies that you do not turn around and block the main application thread, which is what you are proposing to do by using `join()` to block until the background thread completes. If you were using Kotlin instead of Java, you can *almost* get what you want using coroutines -- simplified multi-threading is one of the reasons why developers are moving towards Kotlin and coroutines.

Comment: But, particularly in Java for Android, multi-threading is *hard*. A solution as simple as the one that I pointed you towards is really about as good as it gets. Many, if not most, developers use libraries and frameworks to help solve the hard parts of Android app development. You will see references to things like RxJava, for example, which helps to provide a structured way of doing multi-threading well in Java. RxJava is more general-purpose than is OkHttp, but it also has a steep learning curve, which is why I did not suggest it earlier.

Comment: I understand that blocking the main thread is not something you should do unthinkingly, but to give you more background the user is inputting a registration key that changes the whole app from evaluation mode to full use. The key is sent to my website which checks it's valid and has not been used before then sends back a confirmation (or error message). My opinion is that it is better that the user wait a few seconds to get the confirmation rather than trying to do something else.

Comment: There are better approaches for doing that, such as disabling submit buttons, replacing submit buttons with progress spinners, etc. You then switch the UI to some other state based on the success/failure of the operation, without blocking the main application thread along the way. Besides allowing your app to look better, it also more gracefully handles edge cases, such as it taking significantly longer than a few seconds for the I/O to complete, due to connectivity issues, server problems, etc. It also blends better with solutions to other problems, such as configuration changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CountDownLatch:

```
CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1); // create latch object with counter set to 1
new Thread() {
           public void run() {
               myclass.myMethod();  // Do some work here
               latch.countDown();  // decrement counter from 1 to 0
           }
       }.start();
latch.await();  // await until counter in latch reaches 0
```

You should also consider using some library for handling async operations in Android like rxJava or AsyncTask.

Comment: Simple & elegant!  Note that you will probably have to add: throws InterruptedException  to the method declaration.